# A website has a list of URLs, I need to write a loop that accesses each URL and scrapes two tables

Tags: r, url, xpath, scrape

I'm trying to, ultimately, scrape tables from several different URLs (within the same parent site) in R.

First, I assume I have to scrape the individual game links under "Playoff Series" from https://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2017.html -- the xpath for that table of links is //*[@id="all_all_playoffs"]

then, I want to scrape tables from each of those individual game links (looks like this: https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201705170BOS.html) -- the tables I want are the "basic box score stats" for each team.

(I plan on repeating this for several different years, so typing in each URL--like I do below--is not very efficient)

so far, I can only figure out how to scrape tables from one url (or one game) at a time:

```
games <- c("201705190BOS","201705190BOS","201705210CLE","201705230CLE","201705250BOS")
urls <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/", games, ".html")
get_table <- function(url) {
  url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="div_box_cle_basic"]/table[1]') %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="div_box_bos_basic"]/table[1]') %>%
    html_table()
}

results <- sapply(urls, get_table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, give it a try!

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/NBA_2017.html')

#get all links in the playoff section
playoffs <- page %>%
  html_node('#div_all_playoffs') %>%
  html_nodes('a') %>%
  html_attr('href')

#limit to those that are actually links to boxscores
playoffs <- playoffs[grep('boxscore', playoffs)]

#loop to scrape each game
allGames <- list()
for(j in 1:length(playoffs)){
  box <- read_html(paste0('https://www.basketball-reference.com/', playoffs[j]))

  #tables are named based on which team is there, get all html id's to find which one we want
  atrs <- box %>%
    html_nodes('div') %>%
    html_attr('id')

  #limit to only names that include "basic" and "all"
  basicIds <- atrs[grep('basic', atrs)] %>%
    .[grep('all', .)]

  #loop to scrape both tables (1 for each team)
  teams <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(basicIds)){
    #grab table for team
    table <- box %>%
      html_node(paste0('#',basicIds[i])) %>%
      html_node('.stats_table') %>%
      html_table()

    #parse table into starters and reserves tables
    startReserve <- which(table[,1] == 'Reserves')

    starters <- table[2:(startReserve-1),]
    colnames(starters) <- table[1,]

    reserves <- table[(startReserve + 1):nrow(table),]
    colnames(reserves) <- table[startReserve,]

    #extract team name
    team <- gsub('all_box_(.+)_basic', '\\1', basicIds[i])

    #make named list using team name
    assign(team, setNames(list(starters, reserves), c('starters', 'reserves')))
    teams[[i]] <- team
  }

  #find game identifier
  game <- gsub('/boxscores/(.+).html', '\\1', playoffs[j])

  #make list of both teams, name list using game identifier
  assign(paste0('game_',game), setNames(list(eval(parse(text=teams[[1]])), eval(parse(text=teams[[2]]))), c(teams[[1]], teams[[2]])))

  #add to allGames
  allGames <- append(allGames, setNames(list(eval(parse(text = paste0('game_', game)))), paste0('game_', game)))

}

#clean up everything but allGames
rm(list = ls()[-grep('allGames', ls())])
```

The output is a list of lists.  This isn't great, but the data you want is inherently hierarchical: each game has 2 teams and each team has 2 tables (starters and reserves).  So, the final object looks like:

-allGames

----Game1

-------Team1

----------Starters

----------Reserves

-------Team2

----------Starters

----------Reserves

----Game2 
...

For example, show the table with data on the starters for Cleveland in the last game of the final with:

```
> allGames$game_201706120GSW$cle$starters
          Starters    MP FG FGA  FG% 3P 3PA  3P% FT FTA   FT% ORB DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF PTS +/-
2     LeBron James 46:13 19  30 .633  2   5 .400  1   4  .250   2  11  13   8   2   1   2  3  41 -13
3     Kyrie Irving 41:47  9  22 .409  1   2 .500  7   7 1.000   1   1   2   6   2   0   4  3  26  +4
4       J.R. Smith 40:49  9  11 .818  7   8 .875  0   1  .000   0   3   3   1   0   2   0  2  25  -2
5       Kevin Love 29:55  2   8 .250  0   3 .000  2   5  .400   3   7  10   2   0   1   0  2   6 -23
6 Tristan Thompson 29:52  6   8 .750  0   0       3   4  .750   4   4   8   3   1   1   3  1  15  -7
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to automatically parse the game ids of all the `games` on the site? If so, prior to inputting them into your table parser, you'll want to build a separate scraper that gets the game ids.

Here is how I would do it:

1. Select a starting date, then iteratively ping each site day by day, could use `readLines` to pull back the html string for each date from:
   https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/?month=11&day=4&year=2017

   So just iterate over the month, day, and year in the link
2. From the link above, find the items that are under the hyperlink `final`, or show this in the HTML text `<a href="/boxscores/201711040DEN.html">Final</a>`.

Could use regex to parse each line and search for something like:

`grep('.*<a href=\"/boxscores/.*.html\">Final</a>.*', [object], value = TRUE) %>%
 gsub('.*<a href=\"(/boxscores/.*.html)\">Final</a>.*', '\\1', .)`

This would build out the game links which you can then feed into your parser above.